# Wordpress loop one category per page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

So I have a standalone Wordpress site with a bunch of different categories:

March 2013
February 2013
January 2013
etc...

I'd like the homepage of my Wordpress site to display the latest category. At this moment that would be March 2013. Then if you go back a page, it would display February 2013, go back another page and you're on January 2013, etc.

How would I go about modifying the wordpress loop to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of weird. You want to use months as Categories.

I'd suggest you to tidy your posts in REAL categories to have a better SEO and in your loop you just change the WP_query to show all post of the current month and change the WP_Query for previous entries. But for me it's not a good conception.

Comment: Okay, I don't have to use categories, that is probably wrong. But occasionally there are two "sections" each month like `Early January` and `Late January`.

Comment: I think you got to generate a custom template page with a WP_query which get the current date and check the current year and compare it to the choise. Like "late january" will get 2013 posts and "early january" will get 2012 posts. That's what you want?

Comment: Not exactly. The posts are made in groups, approximately 20 at a time. Usually it's a monthly release but sometimes there's a release of 20 posts around the 1st of the month, and again halfway through. The months don't necessarily correlate to the post groups.